# The Values are not being populated when jumping to another view

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm learning Angular JS I'm I.m making a simple application that should start with a list of persons and when the user clicks in "Update User" it should be redirected to an edit page, which the data should be populated, which is not happening. Here is my code:

HTML of the starting page:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/listview',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/ListView.html'
            })
        .when('/tableview',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/TableView.html'
            })
        .when('/edit/:id',
            {
                controller: 'EditCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/Edit.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/listview' });
}]);

app.controller('EditCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.details = $scope.persons[$routeParams.id];

    $scope.save = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };
});

app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{ name: 'Tiago', city: 'Lisbon', age: 26 },
                      { name: 'Ecem', city: 'Antalya', age: 24 },
                      { name: 'Derya', city: 'Istambul', age: 24 }
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Galaksiyia - TableView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="details in persons">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{details.name}}</td>
            <td>{{details.city}}</td>
            <td>{{details.age}}</td>
            <td><a href="#/edit/{{$index}}">Update User</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Html of the Edit page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Galaksiyia - Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="details.name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="details.city" placeholder="City" /><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="details.age" placeholder="Age" /><br />
        <button ng-click="save()">Update User</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, when the Save button is clicked nothing happening, and according with the code the user should be redirected to the Main Page.

Comment: are you able to route to next page ?

Comment: The scope of the objects are only in the controller which it is using only. In other controllers, it will be undefined.

Comment: @ngLover what do you mean? Passing from the Table Page to the Edit Page? Yes, and the index is being passed correctly

Comment: @ShijuKBabu could you explain that in detail?

Comment: In `SimpleController` you have persons list, which won't be available in `EditCtrl`.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu I hard coded inside the EditCtrl this:

$scope.persons = [{ name: 'Tiago', city: 'Lisbon', age: 26 },
                      { name: 'Ecem', city: 'Antalya', age: 24 },
                      { name: 'Derya', city: 'Istambul', age: 24 }
    ];

And is still without working

Comment: @ngLover nope, isn't working as well

Comment: Can you show your index.html file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to your proplem is to put the data (that must be available in two controllers) into the $rootScope

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $rootScope.persons = [{ name: 'Tiago', city: 'Lisbon', age: 26 },
                      { name: 'Ecem', city: 'Antalya', age: 24 },
                      { name: 'Derya', city: 'Istambul', age: 24 }
    ];
});
```

A better solution is to write a service (factory) and to get the data from that service.

Comment: be sure to change this code as well: `$scope.details = $scope.persons[$routeParams.id];` -> $scope.details = $rootScope.persons[$routeParams.id];`